# Reactjs adding an object to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pusher, flux

I'm using reactjs to populate **state.users** with a new member when he or she signs in.

The following code is working

```
var users = this.state.users;
users.push(member);
this.setState({users: users});
```

But when I try to wrap everything in one line of code it fails

```
this.setState({users: this.users.state.push(member)});
```

When I try the above I get an error further down in my list.jsx

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.users.map is not a function

Any idea what is causing this? I'm thinking that when I use the one line solution the wrong kind of object is passed into the state?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because `.push` returns the new length (int number), not array,

```js
var data = {
    users: []
};

data.users = data.users.push(10);
console.log(typeof data.users); // number
```

> [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - return the new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

You can use `.concat` instead of `.push`

```
this.setState({
   users: this.state.users.concat(member)
});
```

or

```
this.setState({
  users: [...this.state.users, member]
});
```